# How to concatenate integer to string in ERB?

Tags: ruby, string-concatenation

If item_counter=213 then I want to set item_id to "item213". Seems easy but:

```
<% item_id = "item" + item_counter %>
```

results in an error: `can't convert Fixnum into String`

```
<% item_id = "item" + item_counter.chr %>
```

outputs a strange character: `item`

```
   <% item_id = "item#item_counter" %>
```

is understood as `item#item_counter`

What is the correct way to concatenate an integer to a string in ERB (Ruby on rails 3)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`to_s` is the method you're looking for:

```
<% item_id = "item" + item_counter.to_s %>
```

You can also use string interpolation:

```
<% item_id = "item#{item_counter}" %>
```